# R: Converting daily timeseries data to monthly

Tags: r, time-series, xts, stock, risk-analysis

I am trying to find the deltacovar using the systemicR package but I am having trouble reading my csv file properly in xts form for my daily time series data and converting them into monthly data.
I am getting the below mentioned error. How do I fix this error or/and read my data properly? Thank you very much in advance

```
library(SystemicR)
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
Dataset1 <- read.csv('C:/Users/sha03/Desktop/R/intro/data/CC_data_v2.csv',sep = ";"))
v_returns <- numeric(10)
v_returns <- rnorm(10, 0, 0.01)
v_date <- seq(from = as.Date("2015-09-01"), to = as.Date("2021-11-30"), by = "month")
xts_returns <- xts(v_returns, order.by = v_date)
```

> > Error in xts(v_returns, order.by = v_date) :
> > NROW(x) must match length(order.by)

| date | BTC | ETC | LTC | XMR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/2015 | 227.96 | 1.36 | 2.82 | 0.45 |
| 9/2/2015 | 229.5 | 1.31 | 2.82 | 0.45 |
| 9/3/2015 | 227.11 | 1.23 | 2.64 | 0.45 |
| 9/4/2015 | 231.18 | 1.23 | 2.72 | 0.47 |
| 9/5/2015 | 235.9 | 1.36 | 2.94 | 0.48 |
| 9/6/2015 | 240.81 | 1.34 | 3.08 | 0.5 |
| 9/7/2015 | 244.17 | 1.28 | 3.06 | 0.5 |

Comment: You are not supplying `Dataset1` to the function `xts`, so you are trying to sort one vector by a separate vector of unequal length.

Answer (score 1):

Generally check out the `apply.monthly()` function in R and xts.
[apply.monthly: Apply Function over Calendar Periods](https://rdrr.io/cran/xts/man/apply.monthly.html)